# jquery transitionend function kiks in every time I repeat my click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How To prevent openContent(); to kick the `$("#load-content").on("transitionend` each time I click `.show-content` ???

I'm not sure how to stop this `transitionend` to be kicked!  Please heeeelp

```
$('.show-content').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  openContent();
});
$('#load-content').on('click','.prev',function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  closeContent(this);
});
function openContent(){  
    $('#load-content').load('../views/product-page.html');
    $('.container').addClass('loaded');
    $("#load-content").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
    $(this).addClass('animate');
    var body = $("body,html");
    body.animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
});
}
function closeContent(ele){
    var Loaded = !$(ele).closest('.container').hasClass('loaded');
    if (!Loaded) {
        $('.animate').removeClass('animate');
        $("#load-content").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {
            $('.loaded').removeClass('loaded');
            $('#show-content').remove();
        });
    }           
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PcB4U/1/ something like that! not perfect sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally you should namespace the event and the `off` the event after being fired

```
$el.on('transitionend.mynamespace' function(){
    $el.off('transitionend.mynamespace')
});
```

Example:

```
$dropdown.on('transitionend.fadein' function() {
    // some function to be called on transitionend
    doSomething();
    // event will not be called again
    $dropdown.off('transitionend.fadein')
});
```

UPDATE

---

adapted to your code

(you are also using way too many transitionend hendlers)

I created a namespace with e subnamespace 
so now you can say
`.off('transitionend.loadcontent ')`
`.off('transitionend.loadcontent.open ')`
`.off('transitionend.loadcontent.close ')`

Try which one will do what you need

You should generallly read this: http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Also the code doesn't look too amazing.
You should consider a more consequent codingstyle and cache selectors to improve readability and performance. E.g. I replaced all `"` with `'` since you were using mixed quotes.
Maybe run jsHint in your editor and cache all elements that are needed more than once.
But that's not really important for this thing to work.

```
$('.show-content').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    openContent();
});
$('#load-content').on('click', '.prev', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    closeContent(this);
});

function openContent() {
    $('#load-content').load('../views/product-page.html');
    $('.container').addClass('loaded');
    $('#load-content').on('transitionend.loadcontent.open webkitTransitionEnd.loadcontent.open', function() {
        $(this).addClass('animate');
        var body = $('body,html');
        body.animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        $('#load-content').off('transitionend.loadcontent.open webkitTransitionEnd.loadcontent.open');
    });
}

function closeContent(ele) {
    var Loaded = !$(ele).closest('.container').hasClass('loaded');
    if (!Loaded) {
        $('.animate').removeClass('animate');
        $('#load-content').on('transitionend.loadcontent.close webkitTransitionEnd.loadcontent.close', function() {
            $('.loaded').removeClass('loaded');
            $('#show-content').remove();
        });
        $('#load-content').off('transitionend.loadcontent.close webkitTransitionEnd.loadcontent.close');
    }
}
```

Comment: would be nice if you could help as I not sure I can put together that function alone

Comment: thank you so much for all your suggestion. however $('#load-content').on('transitionend.loadcontent.close webkitTransitionEnd.loadcontent.close', function() {
               $('.loaded').removeClass('loaded');
               $('#show-content').remove();
           }); doesn't work! could u double check why please?

Comment: Gotcha it should be $('#load-content').one('transitionend.loadcontent webkitTransitionEnd.loadcontent', function() {
               $('.loaded').removeClass('loaded');
               $('#show-content').remove();
           }); fantastic! thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

you might need

```
   $ele.one('click',function(){...})
```

which allows you to bind the event only one time. after being fired, this event listener will unbind itself. check document here:https://api.jquery.com/one/